# color desaturated image on hover and desaturate again on mouse out html5 css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code is ready but I want the image to get colored (i.e. remove grayscale property of IMG) on mouse hover and when the mouse is out the image should get grayscale again.

If it is not possible only by css. javascript is also ok but please no jquery, I don't know jquery.

The code is below:

```
<style type="text/css">

#ajabox:hover #ajainner{
    height:100px;
    top:-100px;
}

#ajainner{
    width:332px;
    overflow:hidden;
        height:0px;
    background-image:url(../../images/bg_black_50.png);
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
    transition: top .4s ease-in, height .4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: top .4s ease-in, height .4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: top .4s ease-in, height .4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: top .4s ease-in, height .4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: top .4s ease-in, height .4s ease-in;
}

#ajabox{
    width:332px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    height:209px
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-ms-box;
    display:-o-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
span{
     color:#FFF; 
     font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
     left:10px; 
     top:10px; 
     position:relative;
}
img.desaturate { 
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: gray;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<div id="ajabox">
    <img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/123/c/9/adam_jensen__s_army_____________by_gtanmay-d3fh5pw.png" style="width:332px;" class="desaturate"/>
    <div id="ajainner">
        <span>Adam Jensen's Army</span>
        <br />
        <span style="font-size:12px">Made from the CD cover of "Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood"<br />Feat. Adam Jensen(Deus Ex: Human Revolution)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
img { /* Universal settings */
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}
img:not(:hover) {
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter:grayscale(100%);
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter:grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter:grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter:grayscale(0%);
    filter:grayscale(0%);
}
```

The :not selector won't work in older browsers, but neither will filter, so it shouldn't really be much of a problem.

[Example Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ddhboy/rNVpJ/)

Comment: ohhh there is a problem... all other images got the desaturation and saturation on hover property... but dosen't work with the code i gave :(

Comment: If you want it to work with the example you gave, just change img to whatever element(s) you are trying to target. In your case it would be img.desaturate? So img.desaturate, img.desaturate:not(:hover), and img.desaturate:hover

Comment: Sadly, this solution doesn't work on IE10 and above.